# заполнение XML шаблона данными - Python

Tags: python, xml

Задача следующая-  написал парсер, который собирает цены конкурентов из маркетплейса. Нужно результат парсинга сохранить в XML файл определенной структуры.
Данные по одной карточке товара записываются вот в такой блок:

```
<offer sku="232130223">
    <model>iphone 6s white 32gb</model>
        <brand>Apple</brand>
        <availabilities>
            <availability available="yes" storeId="PP1"/>
            <availability available="yes" storeId="PP2"/>
            ...
        </availabilities>
        <cityprices>
            <cityprice cityId="750000000">193000</cityprice>
            <cityprice cityId="710000000">195000</cityprice>
            ...
        </cityprices>
</offer>
```

Здесь cityprice это цена товара в определенном городе с cityID, то есть я по каждому городу  цену получаю отдельном запросом. Товары могут продаваться в разных городах. Так вот мне нужно сделать чтобы все цены попали в этот один блок. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать ?

Ниже кусок кода по этой задаче:

```
import requests
from loguru import logger
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import json
import urllib
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time
import random

async def get_card(self, url, name, sku, cities):
        for city in cities:

            payload="{\"cityId\": "f"\"{city['id']}\""", \"limit\": 5, \"page\": 0, \"sort\":true}"
            pickupPoints = city['pickupPoints'][0]['displayName']
            headers = {
                        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
            proxy = 'http://uname:pass@' + random.choice(self.proxies)
            
            async with self.session.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload) as response:
                try:
                    r = await response.json(content_type=None)
                    price = str(r['offers'][0]['price'])[:-2]
                    self.add_new_offer(name, price, sku, pickupPoints)
                except:
                    pass

def add_new_offer(self,name, price, sku, pickupPoints):
        offer = f'''<offer sku="{sku}">
                            <model>{name}</model>
                            <brand></brand>
                            <availabilities>
                                <availability available="yes" storeId={pickupPoints}/>
                                <availability available="yes" storeId={pickupPoints}/>
                            </availabilities>
                            <cityprices>
                                <cityprice cityId="750000000">{price}</cityprice>
                                <cityprice cityId="710000000">{price}</cityprice>
                            </cityprices>
                        </offer>'''
        self.offers += '\n                        ' + offer

def create_xml(self, CompanyName, CompanyID):
        xmlTemplate = f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <kaspi_catalog date="string"
                      xmlns="kaspiShopping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="kaspiShopping http://kaspi.kz/kaspishopping.xsd">
           <company>{CompanyName}</company>
            <merchantid>{CompanyID}</merchantid>
            <offers>
                {self.offers}
            </offers>
        </kaspi_catalog>'''
        f = open('offers.xml', 'w')
        f.write(xmlTemplate)
        f.close()
```

Comment: Кодик ваш черканите c import

Comment: @СергейШашко, добавил код выше

Comment: А библиотеки какие используете?

Comment: @СергейШашко, добавил import, но я не использую тут не pandas, не xml.etree.ElementTree. Сделал шаблон через f строку

Answer (score 0):

```
id =((750000000, 193000),(710000000,195000))
cc =''
for i in id:
   cc +=f'''{' '*12}<cityprice cityId="{i[1]}">{i[2]}</cityprice>\n'''

res =f'''<offer sku="232130223">
    <model>iphone 6s white 32gb</model>
        <brand>Apple</brand>
        <availabilities>
            <availability available="yes" storeId="PP1"/>
            <availability available="yes" storeId="PP2"/>
            ...
        </availabilities>
        <cityprices>
{cc}
            ...
        </cityprices>
</offer>
'''
```

Comment: Так вопрос ведь не про то, как извлекать данные. Они уже есть, вопрос как их добавлять в XML чтобы в итоге была правильная структура файла. Вы внимательно прочитайте вопрос.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Простите за мою не внимательность. Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но не совсем рабочее решение, Ваш код будет добавлять данные в один offer, а надо ведь и SKU учитывать, это артикул товара.

Comment: Невидя всю картину происходящего не легко дать правельное решения. Я лишь могу дать один из множества напралений для поставленной задачи. А так как у вас опыта поболее моего, я уверен что вы найдете решение.